# Rails + ajaxForm: Use the 'error' callback when error uploading file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajaxform

### Background

I first wanted to upload a file via json and get a response in that way as well.

I'm using:

- Rails 3
- [ajaxForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form)

I soon found out that [you can't get a reponse in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755802/jquery-ajaxform-returning-json-file/2756314#2756314). So, I follow that advice and returned as text.

I'm able to get things working after removing the pre tags. Ugly solution, but it's an ugly problem.

## Problem

Now, my problem is **handling errors**.

### Here's the JS:

```
$('form#new_image').submit(function() {
  $(this).ajaxSubmit({
    dataType: 'text',
    beforeSubmit: showLoading,
    success: imageUploadSuccess,
    error: imageUploadError
  });
  return false;
});

function imageUploadSuccess(data) {
  var jsonObject = $.parseJSON((/<pre>(.+)<\/pre>/.exec(data))[1]);
  //Do something
}

function imageUploadError(data) {
  alert("FAIL!");
}
```

Even if I respond with an error, the success callback (imageUploadSuccess) is always executed.

### Here's my controller:

```
def create
  @image = Image.new params[:file]
  @image.imageable_type = params[:imageable_type]
  @image.imageable_id = params[:imageable_id]

  respond_to do |f|
    if @image.save
      logger.debug "PASSED"
      f.text {render :text => @image.to_json}
    else
      logger.debug "FAIL"
      f.text { render :text => "Fail!", :status => 500 }
    end
  end
end
```

Now, while I could return a json object with `success: false` in it when it fails, it just feels dirty that the success callback is always executed.

**How do I make use of the error callback?**

Comment: you shouldn't rely on a plugin for submitting a form if it leads to too much constraints. There are few lines of js to make: preventing the default submission, making an ajax call with post. From there you can handle whatever case you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that whether you use .ajax or .ajaxForm to submit it, as long as the server responds, the `success` callback will be executed.

So, I have to reply with specially structured json that has a `success: true/false` depending on the situation. It's best illustrated with the controller action (I'm using inherited_resources here, but you get the idea):

```
def create
  create! do |success, failure|
   success.html {redirect_to to}
   success.text do
     image = {
       :id => @image.id,
       :file_name => @image.file_name,
       :success => true
     }
     render :text => image.to_json
   end
   failure.text do
     image = {
      :success => false,
      :errors => @image.errors
     }
     render :text => image.to_json
   end
   success.js
  end
end
```

Comment: "It seems that whether you use .ajax or .ajaxForm to submit it, as long as the server responds, the success callback will be executed." is __wrong__.  If the server responds with a error status the error handler __will__ be ran.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some generic jQuery code to make your ajax submission:

```
$('#btn-submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
      url: $('form').attr('action'),
      data:  $('form').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {},
      error: function(data) {}
    });
});
```

EDIT:

I just saw you're willing to upload file with ajax. Ajax doesn't allow this kind of processing, but there are great alternatives.

I give two examples here (two branches): https://github.com/apneadiving/Pic-upload---Crop-in-Ajax

- with uploadify using flash
- with jQuery Uploader, 100% js (using frames)

Comment: Thanks, I've been tinkering with fileUpload the past couple of hours, but when I do single file uploads I seem to be fighting the system too much. I'll just try this without the ajaxForm as I stated above, and just the "generic jQuery" way. I'll update you on this.

Comment: As I wrote, uploading a file with ajax requires a tailored tool. It won't work with a simple form.